# WebRTC streaming does not work with some browser combinations

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I stream between two browser sites, one is called master and the other is called slave.
Master streams video to slave.
Master is always active, slave sometimes connects.

I initiate the connection on both sides with this configuration:

```
{'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:mystunserveraddress'}]},
{'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true},{'RtpDataChannels': true}]}
```

Master sends offer for receiving no audio and no video.
Slave handles offer and answers with offer for receiving video.
Master handles answer.

Ice candidates are processed on both sides.
Video is attached to peer connection before sending offer.

I tested it to work with following combination of Master->Slave:

- Android Chrome->Linux Chrome - works
- Android Chrome->Linux Firefox - works
- Android Firefox->Linux Firefox - works
- Android Firefox->Linux Chrome - doesn't work
- Linux Chrome->Linux Chrome - works
- Linux Chrome->Linux Firefox - works
- Linux Firefox->Linux Firefox - works
- Linux Firefox->Linux Chrome - doesn't work
- Linux Chrome->Windows Chrome - doesn't work
- Linux Chrome->Windows Firefox - works
- Linux Firefox->Windows Firefox - works
- Linux Firefox->Windows Chrome - doesn't work

Why is it not working for those combinations? No error is given. Everything looks ordinary as normal, but the video element on slave is blank.

Offering audio and video from both ends, or auto does not change anything.

On Firefox master I have two "connected" states and on Chrome slave I have "checking" state.

I have tested on local server and remote server, behaves the same.

It does not work on AppRTC example either.

Comment: its probably not working due to a bug. The implementations in both browsers are not final or bug free.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting, didn't quite got it yet.

Comment: It maybe so, but everywhere they say, that interop between Chrome and Firefox is works from 2013. But I can't get Linux Chrome->Windows Chrome working.

Comment: There are different OS interactions/drivers/versions for the browser on different OS. I would post bug reports with your versions of the software and the errors that are occurring.

Comment: Benjamin is right, chrome on windows and chrome on linux use different stacks. You can post a bug there:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

Side-note: Do not use RtpDataChannels.  It's old, it's Chrome-only, it's non-standard - it wasn't even proposed to the standards.  Chrome now supports standards RTCDataChannels (pc.createDataChannel(...)) which interops with Firefox.

I strongly suspect your video problems are a bug in your JS code, perhaps a dependence on the timing of success callbacks versus other callbacks - or against ICE candidates.  If the Success callback of SetRemoteDescription hasn't returned, you shouldn't add ICE candidates yet for example (queue them and add after success).

If you call using apprtc from Chrome on Linux to Chrome on Windows (and vice-versa), does it work?  It should; this is something people do all the time (on Chrome and Firefox).